Function Between Oscilloscope Trigger and Sampling Storage
I have a query where maybe is stupid but anyway I will dare to ask. How the oscilloscope knows when to start to save the sampling data in his RAM memory in order to process them and display them? I mean like the video shows below if we set the trigger at zero volt the oscilloscope when will find a transition from zero to a higher value (positive edge trigger) it will starts to capture samples (post-triggered data), but how can knows what are the pre-trigger data if it starts to collect data only after the trigger event occurs. Only if it knows in before when the trigger will occur then it could calculate the pre-trigger data duration time in order to start a time before to collect samples.
https://www.tek.com/en/video/the-basics-of-an-oscilloscope-trigger

it starts to collect data only after the trigger event ... do not make that assumption

It's actually collecting data all the time. It's really a question of when it stops collecting data, which is always after the trigger event.

When you start the signal, initially, there won't be any pre-triggered data displayed. The video mentioned that it shows pre-triggered data, but  that's true iff it is available. Say, you have a square wave switching between 2V and 5V and you're triggering at 5V, it won't trigger at 2V, so the pre-triggered voltage will show 2V. But the moment you connect the scope and it triggers, it can't predict and display the pre-triggered value.

It stores it in FIFO, when the trigger event occurs it collects data to fill half FIFO and then stops writing in FIFO. The result is, that you have pre-trigger data (lower half FIFO) and post-trigger data (upper half FIFO)

Not all scopes can do what you describe, but the memory of the scope is essentially like a circular buffer where it's continually taking the ADC data and putting it into a buffer. After triggering the scope can dump data from the circular buffer with data that has occurred before the trigger.
